# How Can I setup Cloudwatch Alarms on SNS Retry and DLQ Entry?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-sns, cloudwatch-alarms, dlq

How can I setup a cloudwatch alarm which should trigger when a SNS topic message is being retried or when there is an entry in my dead letter queue?

Both AWS console setup or cloudformation documentation should be helpful.

I am trying to setup using cloudformation. But I need something as a documentation to create alarms and link them with DLQ/SNS Retries. Any documentation or help is appreciated.